# Redmine pg error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redmine

I installed the latest version of redmine with rails 3.2.6. It works fine in development on a mysql database, but I uploaded it to heroku, which uses postgres. I get this error related to the Setting model and I can't view any page.

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "settings" does not exist
:SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"settings"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
):
app/models/setting.rb:152:in `check_cache'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:81:in `user_setup'
```

I tried debugging it but it seems like anything related to the settings model has problems. Just wondered if anyone ran into this problem or can offer insight.

Comment: I did but you were right, I went back and looked and somehow the setting table didn't get migrated. thanks!

Comment: That SQL is used by ActiveRecord's PostgreSQL adapter to figure out the column structure of a table so if you see errors that look like that then you'll know that you forgot to create a table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 500 internal error getting into redmine welcome page (at browser: localhost:3000).
At console, it says the same error message:

> ... statementInvalid ... relation settings does not exist ...

So I follow Ultimation's trail and go back and do

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake redmine:load_default_data
$ rails server
```

Then I go to browser, and localhost:3000. The error goes away and I am able to see the redmine start page.